# How can I run a program with limited permissions

Tags: permissions, process, privileges, jails

I noticed that a lot of my programs run under the same user like (firefox,chromium,steam,etc...) and therefore should have the same permissions as this user, but I would prefer to limit their accesses.

For example I want none of them to have access to a specific backup directory except a backup process.

Can I somehow run those under another user who is limited but still use them on my kde session normally? (Which I assume can access all my main user's directories.)

Comment: What about `chown root dir; chmod 700 dir`? I.e. change owner to root and deny read from everyone else.

Comment: So i will give the ownership to root and add the privileged processes permission using a group?
What if i want to limit accesses to the whole system except files relevant to the specific process?

Comment: I suppose you could have a separate user for this specific process which would only have access to the backup directory, though I haven't done it before.

Comment: This sounds like what Apparmor was created to solve

Comment: @Andy Apparmor seems to be my solution, i will read about it later, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use `setfacl`:

`setfacl -m u:backup-process-username:rwx backup-folder`

This is an answer to a similar question:
https://askubuntu.com/a/809562/707299